# MVC Model designing for child table display

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, stringify

I have two models linked with the razor page,

```
Model Parent
 Public Property ID as String
 Public Property Notes as String
 Public Property ChildModel as Child

Model Child
Public Property Email as String
Public Property Status as String
```

My back-end table structure is something like,

```
ID | Notes
-------------------
 1 | "test notes 1"


ParentID | Email | Status
-------------------------------------
1        | test1@gmail.com | Pending
1        | test2@gmail.com | Pending
1        | test3@gmail.com | Pending
```

`Status` is a hidden field on the view, so my question is how do I efficiently bind `Email` and `Status` to the model as so that my controller will have access to both the property ?

> One possible approach I see to create hidden field with value of EMail
>   | Status and loop thru in controller to set Email and status. However,
>   it doesnt sound elegant way.

Edit : Code sample

```
Public Class ConfigModel
   Public Property Name as String
   Public Property Users As List(Of UsersModel)
End Class

Public Class UserModel
   Public Property Email() as String
   Public Property Status() as String
End Class
```

### Jquery

```
var Users = [];
Users.push({ 'Email': 'test1@gmail.com', 'Status': 'Pending' },
           { 'Email': 'test11@gmail.com', 'Status': 'Completed' }
          );
obj.data.Users = JSON.stringify(Users);

$.ajax({
                    url: 'Controller/Submit'
                    type: 'POST',                  
                    data: data,
                    success: function (result) {                        

                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, ex) {                        

                    }
});


Public Function Submit(model As ConfigModel) As ActionResult

//Unable to get the 'Users' array which is passed from jQuery

            For Each email In model.Users
                UsersList.Add(New Users With
                                     {
                                         .Email = email.Email,
                                         .Status = email.Status
                                    })
            Next
End Function
```

Comment: I'm assuming by hidden, you don't mean a hidden input field (because that is how you would ensure that you pass it on POST) since that can be accessed on the client side if a user inspects the page. I believe best practice indicates that (depending what you are doing in your view) you would have some form of an indicator property to know which records to then look up again, in order to get those hidden values. Basically, you would just look up the records again in the database in the POST actionresult section of your controller (by ID, maybe determined by a CB bool value to indicate selected).

Comment: Yes, those are hidden field. My dilemma is what is the best approach to handle such situation when you have two columns which are tied together. So In the model I can check something like 
Model.status = Pending then 
sendmail (Model.Email)
If it's single value situation then works perfectly, but In my controller I have multiple emails, and corresponding status against the ID.

Comment: I would still need more context about the business requirement that you are trying to meet? Could you edit your post and expand upon that explanation (about two columns being tied together)?

Comment: @murphy, added code sample for better understanding

Comment: I meant a verbal explanation of what you are trying to accomplish. What do you mean those two fields are tied together? etc. ... Once I know what you are trying to do, then I can (hopefully) provide a relevant answer.